# SQLite: Sum of differences between two dates group by every date

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I have a SQLite database with start and stop datetimes

[image: sqlite start and stop times]

With the following SQL query I get the difference hours between start and stop:

```
SELECT starttime, stoptime, cast((strftime('%s',stoptime)-strftime('%s',starttime)) AS real)/60/60 AS diffHours FROM tracktime;
```

[image: difference hours between two dates]

I need a SQL query, which delivers the sum of multiple timestamps, grouped by every day (also whole dates between timestamps).

The result should be something like this:

- 2018-08-01: 12 hours
- 2018-08-02: 24 hours
- 2018-08-03: 12 hours
- 2018-08-04:  0 hours
- 2018-08-05:  1 hours
- 2018-08-06: 14 hours
- 2018-08-07:  8 hours

Comment: Did your sqlite version support `CTE`?

Comment: yes, CTE is supported

Comment: I wrote an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, use `CTE RECURSIVE` make a calendar table for every date start time and end time, and do some calculation.

**Schema (SQLite v3.18)**

```
CREATE TABLE tracktime(
  id int,
  starttime timestamp,
  stoptime timestamp
);

insert into  tracktime values 
(11,'2018-08-01 12:00:00','2018-08-03 12:00:00');
insert into  tracktime values 
(12,'2018-09-05 18:00:00','2018-09-05 19:00:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    select id,starttime,date(starttime,'+1 day') totime,stoptime
    from tracktime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  id,
            date(starttime,'+1 day'),
            date(totime,'+1 day'),
            stoptime
    FROM cte
    WHERE date(starttime,'+1 day') < stoptime
)

SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%d', starttime),(strftime('%s',CASE 
              WHEN totime > stoptime THEN stoptime
              ELSE totime
            END) -strftime('%s',starttime))/3600 diffHour
FROM cte;

| strftime('%Y-%m-%d', starttime) | diffHour |
| ------------------------------- | -------- |
| 2018-08-01                      | 12       |
| 2018-09-05                      | 1        |
| 2018-08-02                      | 24       |
| 2018-08-03                      | 12       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBqvZniHT4FzuSubu7w3zf/1)

Comment: thanks for this, i like your solution! how can I rewrite the application that the hours are displayed in decimal with two decimal places?

Comment: @baconLX If you want to display  two decimal places you can try to use `printf` function https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBqvZniHT4FzuSubu7w3zf/2

Comment: For example, if I increase the stop times by half an hour, the total time will still show x.00, even though it should actually be x.50.